# What are average comparisons in the `marginaleffects` package?

Tags: r, mixed-model, linear-model, contrasts, marginal-effect

I am confused about what the `avg_comparison` function does in the `marginaleffects` package.

```
library(lme4)
library(marginaleffects)
```

I define a model

```
model <- glmer(y ~ 
                 + t
                 + a 
                 + a:t 
                 + e:t
                 + e:t:a
                 + (1|participant_id) + (1|image_id),
                 data = data, family = binomial, control = glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa"))
```

and am interested in various questions about this model. The variable `t` has 4 groups, one reference and 3 effect groups (it's my experimental condition). Now I want to compare each treatment group to the reference group while all other variables are average.

```
contrasts_h1 <- avg_comparisons(model, var=list(t = "reference"))
contrasts_h1
##       Term               Contrast Estimate Std. Error    z Pr(>|z|)    S    2.5 %
##  t treatment_1 - baseline   0.0716     0.0200 3.57  < 0.001 11.5  0.03235
##  t treatment_2 - baseline   0.0614     0.0196 3.13  0.00177  9.1  0.02289
##  t treatment_3 - baseline   0.0365     0.0196 1.86  t  4.0 -0.00188
```

In order to understand what this actually does I followed the [Marginal Effects Zoo Tutorial](https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/comparisons.html). I ran this to better understand the result:

```
grid_emperical_t1 <- data |> transform(treatment_1=1, treatment_2=0, treatment_3=0, baseline=0)
grid_emperical_bl <- data |> transform(treatment_1=0, treatment_2 =0, treatment_3=0, baseline =1)
yhat_emperical_t1 <- predict(model, newdata = grid_emperical_t1, type = "response")
yhat_emperical_bl <- predict(model, newdata = grid_emperical_bl, type = "response")
contrast_m <- mean(yhat_emperical_t1, na.rm = TRUE) - mean(yhat_emperical_bl, na.rm = TRUE)
contrast_m
## [1] 0.06137143
```

Observe that the `0.06137143` on the bottom fit the `0.0614` in the contrast table well. However, what I do in this second chunk is: I overwrite the treatment condition of *all* data and compare them to each other. I do not compare the predicted mean *inside* the existing condition groups. I find this odd, as there are other covariates that correlate. For example, `e` depends on the treatment group. Hence, computing the `avg_comparison` over all data seems odd. We are forcing data to be in a group that is atypical of that group. I find it more natural to compare `predict(data[t == "treatment_1"])` with `predict(data[t == "treatment_0"])`, i.e. subsetting the data.

Finally, **my questions**:

1. Do I conceptually understand correctly what is going on here?
2. If yes, *why* would you compute average comparisons this way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

##### Question 1

Yes, you have correctly described what `avg_comparisons()` does by default.

##### Question 2

This is an example of “G-Computation”, which is a popular strategy for causal inference in observational data. See this vignette:

https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/gcomputation.html

You can also read more about G-Computation in many textbooks like:

> Hernán MA, Robins JM (2020). Causal Inference: What If. Boca Raton: Chapman & Hall/CRC.

##### Beyond

Note that this G-Computation strategy is the default method, but that you can compute contrasts on arbitrary grids of predictors by specifying the `newdata` argument and using the `datagrid()` helper function.

In particular, note the `by` argument in `datagrid()`, which allows you to create grids with representative values of subgroups. For example,

```r
options(width = 10000)
library(marginaleffects)

mod <- glm(vs ~ am + hp, data = mtcars, family = binomial)

comparisons(mod, newdata = datagrid(hp = mean, by = "am"))
# 
#  Term Contrast Estimate Std. Error      z Pr(>|z|)   S   2.5 %   97.5 %  hp am
#    am    1 - 0 -0.05769    0.09514 -0.606   0.5443 0.9 -0.2442  0.12879 160  0
#    am    1 - 0 -0.70159    0.27437 -2.557   0.0106 6.6 -1.2393 -0.16383 127  1
#    hp    +1    -0.00629    0.00816 -0.770   0.4411 1.2 -0.0223  0.00971 160  0
#    hp    +1    -0.00731    0.00714 -1.024   0.3059 1.7 -0.0213  0.00668 127  1
# 
# Columns: rowid, term, contrast, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high, predicted_lo, predicted_hi, predicted, vs, hp, am 
# Type:  response
```

Which gives you contrasts based on this grid:

```r
datagrid(hp = mean, by = "am", newdata = mtcars)
#        mpg      cyl     disp     drat       wt     qsec vs     gear     carb       hp am
# 1 17.14737 6.947368 290.3789 3.286316 3.768895 18.18316  0 3.210526 2.736842 160.2632  0
# 2 24.39231 5.076923 143.5308 4.050000 2.411000 17.36000  1 4.384615 2.923077 126.8462  1
```

##### Edit in response to a comment by the original poster

First, we compute average predictions. Then, we use the `hypothesis`
argument to compare them pairwise. Please refer to these two vignettes
for very detailed explanations of this code:

- https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/predictions.html
- https://marginaleffects.com/vignettes/hypothesis.html

```r
library(marginaleffects)
mod <- glm(vs ~ am + hp, data = mtcars, family = binomial)

avg_predictions(mod,
  type = "response",
  by = "am",
  hypothesis = "revpairwise")
```

```
  Term Estimate Std. Error    z Pr(>|z|)   S   2.5 % 97.5 %
 1 - 0     0.17     0.0951 1.79   0.0737 3.8 -0.0163  0.356

Columns: term, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high 
Type:  response
```

```r
mean(predict(mod, subset(mtcars, am == 1))) -
mean(predict(mod, subset(mtcars, am == 0)))
```

```
[1] 0.1721376
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response @Vincent. I am not quite sure what to use in practice. Do you know of any guidance when either approach is preferred in practice?

Comment: I noticed that the OP's model violates the marginality principle: it includes interactions of `e` and `type_name` but not their main effects. Will the average comparisons be valid?

Comment: @dipetkov. There are data that are missing by design. `e` describes the properties of the treatment and hence is 0 for the baseline. If we had a main-effect for `e`, the model would be over specified. That's why we removed it from the analysis.

Comment: @carol-eisen I'm not sure there *can* be general guidance here, as the quantity of interest is domain-specific. One thing you could do is use the `by` argument in `avg_comparisons()` --- and *not* in `datagrid()` --- to report separate estimates of the average contrast in different subgroups of your data. That could help you determine if there is heterogeneity in treatment effects. If there is very little heterogeneity, the options you are hesitating between are unlikely to matter much. If there is heterogeneity, then you may want to report the estimates for different subgroups separately.

Comment: Note that you can test for equality between estimates in different subgroups with the `hypothesis` argument.

Comment: @Vincent thank you so for your comments. I am not sure if I understand your remarks. What I am interest in testing is `mean(predict(model, newdata = data[t == "treatment_1"])) == mean(predict(model, newdata = data[t == "treatment_0"]))`. I was not able to reproduce this comparison in `emmeans` nor the `marginal_effects` package.

Comment: @carol-eisen I edited my answer to give you an example. You can use the `hypothesis` argument for that.

Comment: @Vincent awesome! thank you so much!